NVIDIA settings not retained on fullscreen
I am on Ubuntu 24.04LTS and I am running the proprietary NVIDIA driver 550. The default screen settings were very bright and unusable.
Initially after install I noticed that after screen blank the colour correction (brightness, contrast & gamma) settings were not retained, nor were they retained after a restart. I have created a startup script for these settings as well as setting the PowerMizer to performance on startup.
I have a separate script running as a daemon,with an event listener, so that when the screen is turned back on after screen blank the settings are also retained.
But when I put a movie into fullscreen mode after about 5 seconds the screen goes blank for a few seconds and the picture comes back with the default (bright) settings. When leaving fullscreen the screen also goes blank for a few seconds, but the brightness remains. I have tried adjusting the composition pipeline and GSYNC settings in various combinations but no joy.
Any advice as to what can be done?, I have tried setting up another event listener but cannot find the event that occurs when switching to fullscreen. I would like to avoid running another daemon but am open to any solution. Let me know if any more info is needed, any help greatly appreciated.
